# best_in_place error id for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

In my rails app , I create a ratings for rates my sound.And in the rating , the user can add information , like why he give this marks etc..

My ratings work good , but now i want add with best_in_place the edit input for the info.

So In my view #Sound show

```
 <%= best_in_place @rating, :info, :type => :textarea, :nil => "Ajouter un commmentaire à votre vote !" %>
```

And in my controller : Ratings :

```
 def create
      @sound = Sound.find_by_id(params[:sound_id])
                @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])
                @rating.sound_id = @sound.id
                @rating.user_id = current_user.id
                if @rating.save
                    respond_to do |format|
                        format.html
                        format.js
                    end
                end
        end

        def update
            @sound = Sound.find_by_id(params[:sound_id])
                @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_sound_id(@sound.id)
                @rating.sound_id = @sound.id
                if @rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])
                    respond_to do |format|
                        format.html
                        format.js
                    end
                end

        end
```

But when I want edit  "info" with best_in_place , I have this mistake :

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted
>   the id of nil, use object_id

And the lane is :

> @rating = current_user.ratings.find_by_sound_id(@sound.id)

I hope you understand my problem , and you can help me for the in_place_editing works.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the best in place gem uses ajax, so you need to add some code to your controller.
The docs show that the gem comes with a controller helper for responding to json.

```
 respond_to do |format|
if @rating.update_attributes(params[:rating])
  format.html { redirect_to(@sound, :notice => 'Rating was successfully updated.') }
  format.json { respond_with_bip(@rating) }
else
  format.html { render :action => "edit" }
  format.json { respond_with_bip(@rating) }
end
end
```

You also may need to add the jQuery initializer to you document anywhere:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

Hope that works! Also, this is my first stack overflow answer ever!

Comment: I try your solution, but the same problem appear

Comment: Try keeping your old code and just changing format.js to format.json. Also, see if you can find anything in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast). You may need to add a jQuery initializer.